# How to handle already enqueued jobs after number of args in related worker has been reduced?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

Let's say I have a worker with some params:

```
class Foo
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :critical

  def perform(param1, param2, param3)
    ...
  end
end
```

It worked for some time and then I reduced number of worker's args:

```
class Foo
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :critical

  def perform(param1, param2)
    ...
  end
end
```

But there are some jobs with previous number of args in the queue still. What is the best way to handle such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
def perform(param1, param2, _=nil)
```

The underscore is a convention meaning "this argument is unused and ignored" and the nil default means perform will work with 2 or 3 args.

Once the queue is drained of old jobs, you can remove the third arg completely.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to drain the queue (and prevent other jobs from being enqueued) for a period of time or you need to cancel/delete those jobs.

You can cancel those jobs but the author of Sidekiq recommends against it.  The sidekiq [wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-cancel-a-sidekiq-job) explains it as:

> Sidekiq does not provide this functionality; it's safer and better for the application to do it. You should implement something like this:

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(args)
    return if cancelled?
    # do stuff
  end

  def cancelled?
    Sidekiq.redis {|c| c.exists("cancelled-#{jid}") }
  end

  def self.cancel!(jid)
    Sidekiq.redis {|c| c.setex("cancelled-#{jid}", 86400, 1) }
  end
end
```

The safest bet is likely option 1.